# How to load Listview records dynamically with bottom progressbar

Tags: android, listview

in my app I am using listview and in my listview I have to load 100 and more records at a time.

I think this is too much of a burden, that's why I decided to load the first 10 records at the beginning, then when I scroll the next 10 records, and so on...like that way using progressbar at bottom of listview.

After all the records are loaded, I have to show no "records available".

Can anybody help me please?

How can I do this?

### code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    String[] arrayS = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"};
    View footer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actvity);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.load);

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            list.add(arrayS[i]);
        }
        //Add footer view:-
        footer = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.progress, null, false);
        footer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        listView.addFooterView(footer);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(ad);

       //Implementing scroll refresh:-

        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstItem, int visibleItemCount, final int totalItems) {

                footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not my question and i already added please read my question once

Comment: Use `Endless Adapter`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Comment: for this small logic need not any downloadable projects